# Проблема с curl запросом

Tags: php

```
<?php
$myCurl = curl_init();
$data = array(
    'saleid'=>'328751050',
'location'=>'shop_browse',
'amount'=>'285',
'internal_search'=>'',
'csrf'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);
curl_setopt( $myCurl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.opskins.com/ICart/AddToCart/v1/' );
curl_setopt( $myCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
 'origin: https://opskins.com', 
 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br', 
 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7', 
 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36', 
 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
 'accept: */*', 
 'referer: https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_browse&app=730_2', 
 'authority: api.opskins.com', 
 'cookie: chok=chok1; woop=woop; yes=no',
 ));
curl_setopt($myCurl,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

 curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
 curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8000');
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '1.1.1.1');
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'xxxx:xxxxxx');
curl_setopt( $myCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt ($myCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);        

 echo 'Error curl: ' . curl_error($myCurl);

curl_close($myCurl);
?>
```

Пытаюсь нажать на кнопку на целевом сайте, действие не проходит, ошибку не возвращает.

[image: скринчик]

Comment: ? нет ошибки же

Comment: @Naumov "403 Forbidden
Missing or invalid CSRF token.OK!!" токен перепроверил, все ровно ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас "вывод ошибки" выполняется безусловно, а сам запрос не выполняется.

Нужно:

```
if (curl_exec ( $myCurl ))
    echo 'OK!!';    // сделать что-то полезное по обработке вашего запроса
else
    echo 'Error curl: ' . curl_error($myCurl);
```

Comment: Исправил, теперь загружается пустая страница

Comment: Вывод результата не обязателен, для начала нужно что бы прошел POST запрос который посылается при нажатии кнопки

Comment: у вас установлена опция CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER. Это значит, что curl_exec будет возвращать ответ сервера как результат функции, а не печатать его на страницу.

Comment: точно )). Смотрю в книгу вижу фигу. Убрал теперь "403 Forbidden
Missing or invalid CSRF token.OK!!" Токен ещё раз проверил, указан верно. Но ошибка

Comment: а это уже зависит от серверного скрипта, если с токеном все в порядке.

Comment: от моего скрипта или скрипта целевого сайта?

Comment: целевого. (Но проверьте самым тщательным образом csrf, как вы его получаете и как передаете.)

Comment: Стоит пробовать сделать через генерацию файлов с ключами и сертификатами (keys.pem, cert.pem и ca.crt). И затем указанием и размещением этих файлов со скриптом

Comment: Уже не понимаю о чем вы. Csrf - это не ssl ключи\сертификаты, никак не связано. Почитайте на википедии. Упрощенно говоря, тот сайт генерирует csrf-токен при аутентификации на сайте, это некая строка. При каждом последующем запросе вы указываете эту строку.

Comment: "Пользователи часто задают вопрос: как парсить сайты защищенные ssl сертификатами. У cURL для этого есть специальные средства. Сертификат подключается, как обычный файл плюс файл с ключами. Единственное ограничение: cURL на php понимает только сертификаты формата pem, а большинство серверов работает на связке p12+crt"  Цитата с одного ресурса, может я что то не так понял.

Comment: Причем здесь сертификаты и ssl? Ответ сервера `Missing or invalid CSRF token`с ssl никак не связан.

Comment: Понятно , а какими ещё средствами можете посоветовать решить эту задачу ?

Comment: 1. Вам надо почитать и понять, что такое CSRF и CSRF-токен. 2. Получать его (например, при аутентификации) и передавать серверу при запросе.